How to enable the VM Platform feature and how to ensure virtualization is enabled in BIOS when running WSL2 (Ubuntu) on a Windows11 VM in VirtualBox
I have running Windows 11 Enterprise in Virtual Box 7.0.22.
I was able to install the wsl system itself in Win 11. So  I can run the wsl command in PowerShell. E.g.:
$ wsl --list
WSL has no installed distributions

I then installed the Ubunti distro:
$ wsl --install Ubuntu-22.04

Then install itself succeed, but the lauching of  the distro gave me:
WslRegisterDistribution failed with error: 0x80370102
Please enable the Virtual Machine Platform Windows feature and ensure virtualization is enabled in the BIOS.

How can I enable the Virtual Machine Platform Windows feature and ensure virtualization is enabled in the BIOS in the VirtualBox VM?
(Note: I found a few similar questions (but not the same!), none of them with applicable answers....)

Enable it manually through Optional Windows features. You don’t tell us which version of Windows 11 not that it should matter since I don’t believe any version of Windows 11 Enterprise doesn’t support either WSL 2 or VM Platform but the solution to 0x80370102 is well documented

This question is similar to: WSL error 0x80370102 while installing Ubuntu. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
